# php login script help needed. Server error, what's the problem?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="jmtoday" class=" no_js">
<head>
    <title>Login | JM Today </title>
    <link href="Mainstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" ></link>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("navbar.php"); ?>
    <div id="wrap">


        <?php 
        checklogin();
        $check=checklogin();
        if($check ==3){
            confirmcookie($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
        }   

        ?>

        <?php

        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('jmtdy', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        function checklogin(){
            if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookpass'])){

            $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $_COOKIE['cookpass'];
            return 3;
            }

            elseif(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){
                if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
                    $user=mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']);
                    $pass=mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
                    $result=mysql_query("select password from users where username=$user and active='1'");
                }

                else{
                    die('<p class="statusmsg">You didn\'t fill in the required fields.</p>');
                }   

                if(!$result || (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)){
                    die('<p class="statusmsg">The username you entered is incorrect, or you haven\'t yet activated your account. Please try again.</p>');
                }

                $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $dbarray['password']=stripslashes($dbarray['password'];
                $password=stripslashes($pass);
                if($dbarray['password'] != $password)){
                    die('<p class="statusmsg">The password is incorrect. Please try again.</p>');   
                }

                $_SESSION['username']=$user;
                $_SESSION['password']=$password;
                if(isset($_POST['remember']){
                    setcookie("cookname", $_SESSION['username'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
                setcookie("cookpass", $_SESSION['password'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
        }
      }
        else{
            die('<p class="statusmsg"> You came here by mistake, didn\'t you? </p>');
        }
      }

      function confirmcookie($username, $password){

        $result = mysql_query("select password from users where username = '$username'");

        if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            die('<p class="statusmsg">The username you entered is incorrect or you have set an incorrect cookie</p>');
        }

        $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $dbarray['password']  = stripslashes($dbarray['password']);
        $password = stripslashes($password);

        if($password!=$dbarray['password']{
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            die('<p class="statusmsg">The password you entered is incorrect or you have set an incorrect cookie.</p>'); 
        }
        }



        ?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks guys, one more question. I added this piece of code right under the tag, over the tag, but it doesn't seem to show up. Could you please help me?

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="jmtoday" class=" no_js">
<head>
    <title>Login | JM Today </title>
    <link href="Mainstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" ></link>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("navbar.php"); ?>

    <div id="wrap">


        <?php 
        $check=checklogin();
        if($check == true){
            confirmcookie($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
        }   

        ?>

        <?php

        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('jmtdy', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        function checklogin() {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookpass'])){

            $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $_COOKIE['cookpass'];
            return true;
            }

            elseif(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){
                if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
                    $user=mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']);
                    $pass=mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
                    $result=mysql_query("select password from users where username='$user' and active='1'");
                }

                else{
                    die('<p class="statusmsg">You didn\'t fill in the required fields.</p>');
                }   

                if(!$result || (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)){
                    die('<p class="statusmsg">The username you entered is incorrect, or you haven\'t yet activated your account. Please try again.</p>');
                }


                if($dbarray['password'] != $password){
                    die('<p class="statusmsg">The password is incorrect. Please try again.</p>');   
                }
                $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $dbarray['password']=stripslashes($dbarray['password']);
            $password=stripslashes($pass);
                $_SESSION['username']=$user;
                $_SESSION['password']=$password;
                if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                    setcookie("cookname", $_SESSION['username'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
                setcookie("cookpass", $_SESSION['password'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
        }
      }
        else{
            die('<p class="statusmsg"> You came here by mistake, didn\'t you? </p>');
        }

      } 


      function confirmcookie($username, $password){

        $result = mysql_query("select password from users where username = '$username'");

        if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            die('<p class="statusmsg">The username you entered is incorrect or you have set an incorrect cookie</p>');
        }

        $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $dbarray['password']  = stripslashes($dbarray['password']);
        $password = stripslashes($password);

        if($password!=$dbarray['password']){
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            die('<p class="statusmsg">The password you entered is incorrect or you have set an incorrect cookie.</p>'); 
        }
        }



        ?>
        </div>
<div class="footer"><p class="copyright">JMToday &copy; 2011</p><p class="right">A Samir Ghobril Production</p></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is Mainstyle.css for the footer:

```
div.footer
{
    background-color: #009933;
    padding: 0.1em;
    color: white;
    clear: left;
    }
p.copyright
{
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
    font-size: 10px;
    }
    p.right
    {
        margin-left: 190px;
        font-size: 10px;
        }
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: why are you calling checklogin() immediately after you have already called it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what the error is (since you haven't specified it) but try changing the SQL Query from `select password from users where username=$user and active='1'` to `select password from users where username='$user' and active='1'` (not the quotes around `$user`).

Also, return something better from your methods than '3'.  In months time you will come back and wonder what the hell you meant by '3'.

Answer (score 1):

A closing parenthesis is missing line 51.

(The error should be displayed in your web server log).

In

```
  $dbarray['password']=stripslashes($dbarray['password'];
```

should be

```
  $dbarray['password']=stripslashes($dbarray['password']);
```

Comment: Closing parenthesis also missing from Ln. 83, `if($password!=$dbarray['password']{` should be `if($password!=$dbarray['password']){`

Answer (score 0):

@Samir Ghobril: Update the portion of `Mainstyles.css` which you posted with these rules --

```
div.footer
{
    background-color: #009933;
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.1em;
}
p.copyright
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 120px;
}
p.right
{
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

You should also update your HTML `<head>` with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login | JM Today </title>
    <link href="Mainstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

so that it will [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) for the `DOCTYPE` you're using.

Comment: I did all that but it didn't help.

Comment: @Samir Ghobril: Is it still not displaying the footer at all or is there a different problem? I'm really struggling to help you because I don't have a copy of your full source-code; could you perhaps use jsfiddle.net to post a copy of the output of your site's code (view the source in your browser to get it) as well as your complete `Mainstyles.css`?